# Vue & Firebase: Dom not updating when deleting document

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Im working on a web application where the user can add and delete a notification.

In order to find the right notification to delete in firestore, i have added an id field to the notification document, and added the same id to the data-id attribute on the notification in the DOM. I then use the .where method to find the document and delete it.

The problem comes when i call the `getNotifications()` function to update the DOM. It seems like it takes a few milliseconds before the document is deleted, so the `getNotifications()` is being called before the document is gone. Therefore it sometimes returns the collection with the deleted notification still in it and the notification is still rendered to the DOM.

I tried setting a timeout for 100 milliseconds before calling the function, and then everything works fine. However, it does not seem like the best solution.

Anyone have a good solution for this? Any help, is much appreciated! :)

```
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                messages: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            getNotifications() {
                const self = this;
                const db = firebase.firestore()
                this.messages = [];
                db.collection("messages").get()
                    .then(function(snapshot){
                        snapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                            self.messages.push(doc.data());
                        })
                    })
            },

            deleteNotification(e) {
                const self = this;
                const id = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("data-id");
                const db = firebase.firestore()
                db.collection("messages").where("id", "==", id).get()
                    .then(function(res) {
                        res.forEach(function(doc) {
                            doc.ref.delete();
                            console.log("Document deleted")
                        })
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        self.getNotifications();
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error deleting document: ", error)
                    })
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.getNotifications()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem I experienced during my first project with firebase as well. The easiest way to resolve this problem is to use realtime updates. You could configure the `getNotifications()` method in a way that loads the notifications initially and also subscribes to updates. This means that you don't have to refresh the notifications on delete manually - the subscriptions does that for you. The subscriptions usually reacts to deletes within a couple of milliseconds.

You can take a look at the documentation at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) page.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

1. If you already have the id, you do not need to go and fetch the document in-order to delete it. You can simply do something like this:

```
const ref = db.collection("messages").doc(id)
await ref.delete()
```

2. The reason your code does not work, is because you are performing an asyncronis action when you delete the doc, but you are not waiting for that operation to resolve before you return and move on to the next .then block. With your se-up you'll end up with nested .then/.catch block which is not ideal.
3. Check out Async/Await :)